# Accessing internet from Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 13.10. Everything seems ok accept t internet connection. It does not see any wireless internets including mine. I'm guessing it doesn't see my card. I previously had windows 7 and vista on the machine I am using and the internet connected at install with no problem. The card is BCM 4311 802.11b/g WLAN. Can you help.

g.dgibby

Comment: If you type `ifconfig` in a terminal, does the output include a WLAN interface (usually `wlan0`)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being of specific help. But I want to share what I did. I had Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. I wanted to upgrade. I made a live DVD of Ubuntu 13.10. I booted my system. Automatically it connected to my internet connection through LAN port of my WiFi router. Worked on all aspects. Downloaded large files. Then I clean-installed Ubuntu 13.10 only, on my whole HDD. It auto-configured my internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the drivers are not installed. You can try plugging a CAT cable and go to `System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers`, the right driver will probably be there.